# why scipy.optimize.basinhopping give different results

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, minimization, scipy-optimize-minimize

I need to find global minimum of a complex function.
I use basinhopping from scipy.optimize. when I changed method, example method="nelder-mead" vs "L-BFGS-B" or initial guess x0, they gave me different results, especially in values of x which I need to get to use in next steps. x[5] = 0.6 with "nelder-mead" but x[5]=0.0008 with "L-BFGS-B" although the function value is similar 2055.7795 vs 2055.7756 (all of these has "success: TRUE"). I thought basinhopping finds global minimum. So it should give the same result, no matter what method or initial guess I use.
Anyone can explain why please? and suggest what I should do to find global minimum and check if it is global (not local).

Thank you

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Hi Frank Yellin, here is my code:  <br/> a=([])

Comment: Hi Frank Yellin, here is my code:  
a=np.array([0.45275208,  0.32413238, -0.30483703,  0.99848052,  0.55297566,
        4.26764045,  1.03994821,  0.25612404, -4.58725626,  0.67264732,
        0.17100111, -3.20751967])
bnds = ((-1, 1), (-1, 1),(-1,1),(0,None),(0,None),(None,None),(0,None),(0,None),(None,None),(0,None),(0,None),(None,None))
minimizer_kwargs = dict(method="nelder-mead", bounds=bnds)
res=basinhopping(neg_loglike,a,minimizer_kwargs=minimizer_kwargs). Sorry I am new to stack. I tried to read how to format comments but could not make it work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The basin-hopping method is not guaranteed to give the global minimum for any function. Also it is not deterministic, at there is a random component in the way it will explore the vicinty, as described in the help about `take_step` argument [a](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html#:%7E:text=The%20default%20step%2Dtaking%20routine%20is%20a%20random%20displacement%20of%20the%20coordinates)

If you want to reproduce the same result in two different calls in addition to using the same method you must use the same `seed` parameter.

Also using the same seed should increase the likelihood of giving the same result using different local optimizer methods.